# Creating WMS with QGIS Server using data from PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, wms, qgis-server

I am trying to publish a WMS via QGIS using QGIS Server. It works when the data for the QGIS project are shapefiles that I put in the same folder as the project on the QGIS Server (/usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis-server/projectfolder).

Now I have data that are stored in a PostGIS database. When trying to load the WMS in OpenLayers it doesn´t load the requested WMS layer. I assume that the problem is that it fails to connect to the database since the password is not stored anywhere. I stored the connection to the database in QGIS Desktop but it looks like this information is not passed to the Server.

I am using:

```
QGIS-Version: 2.14.8-Essen
Apache-Version: 2.4.7
PostgreSQL-Version: 9.3.16
PostGIS: 2.1.2 r12389
```

Comment: i know its an old thread. but still were you able to solve the issue, if yes would you like to share the steps?

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help

you need to edit pg_hba.conf file and change the connection methos as md5:

# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket

local    all             postgres                                md5

Restart postgresql server

Check for datasource tag in your .qgis project file which you have copied in your 'cgi-bin/poject/' location and then edit the proper user and password for your database.

Resart the apache and try it again.